# Elasticsearch "AND" Operator Not working as expected with Highlight Query

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm encountering an issue with Elasticsearch where I'm using a highlight query with the "AND" operator, but it's matching a document that doesn't contain all the specified terms in the query. Here's my Elasticsearch query and the document

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "bidAwardId": [
                "05141cde-fd82-4c50-8751-72484bbdafe4"
            ],
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "aocDescription.strValue": {
                "fragment_size": 150,
                "highlight_query": {
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "description.strValue" : {
            "query" : "solar stud road",
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

highlight in the output is following:

```
"highlight" : {
          "description.strValue" : [
            "Remaining Work of Widening and Strengthening of Simdega-Rengari-Kersai-Bolba upto Orissa Border <em>Road</em>"
          ]
        }
```

the highlight field contains the fragment that doesn't contain solar or stud. which should have been the case given the match query has "AND" operator in it.

Comment: aocDescription, description is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you are specifying in the `highlight_query` parameter is only used to extract keywords for highlighting. No attempt is made to actually check if it matches the document being highlighted or not or enforce the boolean logic or your query. It is actually true even for the main query.

Please check the [documentation on the highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/highlighting.html). It literally says at the top in the Note section

> Highlighters don’t reflect the boolean logic of a query when extracting terms to highlight. Thus, for some complex boolean queries (e.g nested boolean queries, queries using `minimum_should_match` etc.), parts of documents may be highlighted that don’t correspond to query matches.

You might try to switch to the `plain` highlighter. This highlighter actually indexes a document in memory in order to better determine which fields matched and where. So, while it is much slower and takes more memory, it typically produces results that are closer to what you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to do something like. highlight only if highlight query is valid?

Comment: I think the best you can do here is to switch to `plain` highlighter. It can be slow if you are retrieving large documents, but it tends to be more "true" to the query.

Comment: I am highlighting with a different query than search. could that be some issue? plain highlighter is not respecting the operator "AND" in the match query as well

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my answer it is far from perfect. The information about why something was matched is not captured during the search process, so highlighter has to reverse-engineer the answer and it does a pretty sloppy job at it. The plain highlighter is the closest but even it is not perfect.